# Mac OS X - configuring ntpd server with on LAN with D-Link DIR-655

Tags: macos, router, lag, ntp, dir-655

This question is pretty specific, but I hope someone will have seen this error elsewhere. I am configuring a machine running OS X 10.5.8 to be an NTP server for machines connected to a LAN that is not connected to the Internet. I am not too worried about knowing the "right" time on all the machines, but rather worried about making sure everyone has the same notion of time.

I configured the NTP daemon on Mac by turning on the Set date and time automatically in System Preferences, using the server's clock, 127.127.1.0 as the reference clock. I figured I should see if the server can NTP query itself before proceeding to the clients.

The weird part is when I run the ntpq -p command in a command-prompt when connected to my D-Link DIR-655 (firmware: 1.33), it hangs for about a minute or so each time before finally giving me some output. I thought the problem might have to do with Port Forwarding, so I configured the router to forward port 123 for the IP of the server, but that did not improve the situation.

When I run the ntpq -p command on my school's network, on a Linksys WRT54G router, or with the wireless Airport card turned off - I have absolutely no problems - the command returns a response instantly.

Is this normal? I can see why a query might take a minute or so, but I don't understand why one router does it faster than the other.

I tried messing around with the ntp.conf file adding the burst, minpoll, and maxpoll options:

```
server 127.127.1.0 burst minpoll 4 maxpoll 5
```

Figuring that perhaps I am polling too often and the configuration file is slowing me down, but even with this, the ntpq still hangs on the D-Link DIR-655, but does just fine on the other routers.

Any thoughts on where the lag is coming from or if the lag is even a problem?

Answer (score 1):

So you're saying that when your Mac is associated to the D-Link box, and run `ntpq -p` *on your Mac*, that it hangs? But the same command doesn't hang when your Mac is connected to the Internet other ways, or via other wireless gateways?

Next time you're associated to the D-Link, do an `ipconfig getpacket en1` and see if the D-Link's DHCP server is returning a time server option in the list of DHCP options.

If the D-Link's NTP client is enabled, and you can disable it, consider disabling it and see if that makes a difference.

Try running `tcpdump -i en1 -vns0 port 123 or arp or icmp` to see what happens NTP-wise (and ARP- and ICMP-wise) on the network when you issue your `ntpq -p` command.

Look at /var/log/system.log for any interesting messages from ntpd.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Perhaps name lookups are slow? Try `ntpq -pn` (option `n` disables name lookups).